# zedgraph common majortick for all y axis

Tags: zedgraph

I'm using Zedgraph to display multiple y axis (both YAxis and Y2Axis).
When having multple yaxis it becomes rather hard to compare curves with all the major ticks. On the picture below each curve has its own major tick:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/70476173/problem.png

I would like the graph to share the same major ticks so that it is easy to compare the curves. I have tried with the code:

```
        //majorTickCount = 12.0
        var min = Math.Floor(yAxis.Scale.Min);
        var max = Math.Ceiling(yAxis.Scale.Max);
        var step = (max - min) / majorTickCount;

        var wholeStep = step; 
        max = min + wholeStep * majorTickCount;
        //yAxis.Scale.MajorStepAuto = true;

        //yAxis.Scale.MajorStepAuto = false;
        //yAxis.Scale.MinGrace = 0;
        //yAxis.Scale.MaxGrace = 0;

        yAxis.Scale.Min = min;
        yAxis.Scale.Max = max;
        yAxis.Scale.MajorStep = wholeStep;
        yAxis.Scale.BaseTic = min;
```

This seems to create the desired effect, but with a problem:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/70476173/problem2.png

The red curves 2nd and 3rd point has the value 6, but as you can see on the picture, the point lies below the majorgrid for 6. I believe the problem is that the majorstep is calculated to 2.5 and the y axis label displaying 6 should rather be 6.1 or something like that.

TL;DR: How do I make all my y axes share the same major steps

Any idea of how I can scale the y axis so that they share the same major grid?